# What does "below" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> We appreciate the opportunity to address Mr. XX complaint below.

What does "below" mean? Does it mean "the complaint written below" or "We appreciate the opportunity to address it below (which means that they will address it in the below space/paragraph)"?

Comment: Surely, the answer will become known by reading what actually **is** written below: the complaint or its response. (It's not impossible for it to be both things.) As for the sentence itself, there *is* no context that's been given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ambiguous.

In order to avoid the ambiguity, one can use "written" before "below." Then it becomes clear the complaint is below. Otherwise, the sentence may be interpreted in 2 ways.

However, my first thought is that the complaint is going to be addressed below. Perhaps it's because of the absence of that "written" after "complaint" in your sentence.